Optional argument type annotation
If we want a function that takes an optional argument x, we'll commonly do this:
def f(x: int | None = None) -> None:
    if x is None:
        print("No value was given.")
    else:
        print(f"{x=}")

Simple stuff, until you want None to be a legitimate value, yet you still want to know if the argument was not provided. A common trick here is this:
_undef = object()


def f(x=_undef):
    if x is _undef:
        print("No value was given.")
    else:
        print(f"{x=}")

Now, because _undef is "private" inside the module, and not meant to be used outside, f() is the only call that should print "No value was given.". I like that trick, although it's been a while since I last used it.
The problem is: how to type annotate that?
My first idea was this:
from typing import Literal


_undef = object()


def f(x: int | None | Literal[_undef] = _undef) -> None:
    if x is _undef:
        print("No value was given.")
    else:
        print(f"{x=}")

This, sadly, does not work because _undef is an invalid argument for Literal.
I have found this workaround:
import enum
from typing import Literal


class _undef(enum.Enum):
    undef = enum.auto()


def f(x: int | None | Literal[_undef.undef] = _undef.undef) -> None:
    if x is _undef.undef:
        print("No value was given.")
    else:
        print(f"{x=}")

and this works, but it seems so needlessly convoluted.
I do know about kwargs, but that brings its own problems in usage and typing.
Is there a neat way to do - and type annotate! - an optional argument when None is one of the legitimate values?

Similar: Type-hinting parameters with a sentinel value as the default

_undef is a little over engineered. As the suggested duplicate (I won't singlehandedly close the question by voting for it as such, but I agree with it) indicates, you can define class A: pass and use type[A] as the type hint, using the type itself as the sentinel. The duplicate also refers you to PEP 661, which proposed a dedicated sentinel factory be added to the standard library.

I sometimes use inf as a sentinal values.  Integer = NewType("Integer", int | Literal[math.inf])

Thank you all. I was unaware of "sentinels". So, for now, either the enum approach or the class one seem to be the way to go.

@James, a small problem with inf is that it's a legit value (of type float). Luckily, not a problem in this case, but also not a general solution.

unittest.mock.sentinel also exists. There are a lot of options, though I'm not sure any one of them is strictly "recommended", so there's a lot of potential for this job e closed as opinion-based.

One question: are you concerned about multiple values of whatever type you choose being possible?

@chepner, not sure what you mean. I am concerned about recognising "there was no value given" while also being able to accept None.

I mean, if your function were def f(x: int | None | type[A]): if x is A: ..., would you be concerned if someone try to pass type('B' (A,),{}) as a sentinel. (That would pass type-checking, but would not be the expected sentinel.)

Sentinels are one of the use cases where you really do want a singleton type.

(Python does have additional singleton types available--e.g., ... is the lone value of type types.EllipsesType. Using ... as a sentinel might be aesthetically unpleasant, but giving it another name, like FSentinel = ... would still allow you to pass FSentinel as an argument but test for ... inside the function, while using types.EllipsesType as part of the type hint.)

@chepner, I am ok with the scenario that you've mentioned because "undef" is supposed to be used only inside my module. So, if someone does type("undef2", (_undef,), dict()), they are doing something naughty and that's on them.
Given that the other topic addresses this same issue, this one can be closed as duplicate, but I don't think that I can do that.

Following the link from the comments, the class approach seems the best, as it only has 3 lines of straightforward code:
class _undef:
    pass


T_undef = Type[_undef]

With that defined, the function above would look like this:
def foo(x: int | None | T_undef = _undef) -> None:
    if x is _undef:
        print("No value was given.")
    else:
        print(f"{x=}")

As @chepner pointed out, this fails if someone subclasses _undef, which they shouldn't do, as _undef is protected and shouldn't be used outside of the module. But, if we want to address this, we can use the trick from this answer about "final" classes, giving us this solution:
from typing import Type


class Final(type):
    """
    Metaclass for classes that cannot be subclassed,
    """

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        """
        Return a new instance of `cls`, i.e., a new class.
        """
        for b in bases:
            if isinstance(b, Final):
                raise TypeError(
                    f"type {b.__name__!r} is not an acceptable base type",
                )
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)


class _undef(metaclass=Final):
    """
    "Undefined" value.
    """


T_undef = Type[_undef]


def foo(x: int | None | T_undef = _undef) -> None:
    """
    Print the value of `x` if it was given, or the appropriate message if not.
    """
    if x is _undef:
        print("No value was given.")
    else:
        print(f"{x=}")


foo()

This passes mypy checks and also disallows subclassing, i.e., this:
class _undef2(_undef):
    """
    This'll fail.
    """

will raise a TypeError exception.
